# Sort doubly-grouped df by value column corresponding to only one of the groups

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a `pd.DataFrame` that is the result of `.groupby(['Product', 'Salesperson']).sum()`. I would now like to sort the Product column in order of Sales by Product (not Sales by Product and Salesperson). Then inside each Product group sort by each Salesperson's Sales.

Here is my starting `df`:

[image: sample]

And here is my desired answer `a1` with some notes to clarify the ordering process:

[image: desired-answer]

Below is my sample `df` and my desired answer `a1` with a simple assertion test.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal
import numpy as np

s1 = {'Product': {0: 'Soap',
                  1: 'Soap',
                  2: 'Pencil',
                  3: 'Paper',
                  4: 'Paper',
                  5: 'Bags',
                  6: 'Bags'},
      'Salesperson': {0: 'Jack',
                      1: 'Jill',
                      2: 'Jill',
                      3: 'Jack',
                      4: 'Barry',
                      5: 'Barry',
                      6: 'Jack'},
      'Sales': {0: 40, 1: 20, 2: 500, 3: 50, 4: 10, 5: 450, 6: 100}}

a1 = {'Product': {0: 'Bags',
                  1: 'Bags',
                  2: 'Pencil',
                  3: 'Paper',
                  4: 'Paper',
                  5: 'Soap',
                  6: 'Soap'},
      'Salesperson': {0: 'Barry',
                      1: 'Jack',
                      2: 'Jill',
                      3: 'Jack',
                      4: 'Barry',
                      5: 'Jack',
                      6: 'Jill'},
      'Sales': {0: 450, 1: 100, 2: 500, 3: 50, 4: 10, 5: 40, 6: 20}}

df = pd.DataFrame(s1).set_index(['Product', 'Salesperson']) # sample
a1 = pd.DataFrame(a1).set_index(['Product', 'Salesperson']) # desired answer

print(df)
print(a1)

def my_sort(df):
    raise NotImplementedError

my_answer = my_sort(df)

assert_frame_equal(my_answer, a1)
```

Comment: Does not work. That is sorting the index alphabetically. I want the sort done by the value of `Sales` of `Product`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `groupby` by `'Product'` and create the dummy columns `'sum'` and `'max'`, which you can use by sorting:

```
g = df.groupby('Product')['Sales']
df['sum'] = g.transform('sum')
df['max'] = g.transform('max')
df.sort_values(['sum', 'max', 'Sales'], ascending=False)\
.drop(['sum', 'max'], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
                     Sales
Product Salesperson       
Bags    Barry          450
        Jack           100
Pencil  Jill           500
Paper   Jack            50
        Barry           10
Soap    Jack            40
        Jill            20
```

Comment: Does not work. Barry `Paper` should directly follow Jack `Paper`.

Comment: @cpage Should be OK now. Soap and paper groups have equal sums.

Comment: yes it's a tricky edge case with equal sums. That's why I provided assertion test. I would like Paper to come before Soap though since Paper has a Salesperson sales of 50 (Jack) that is greater than Soap's highest Salesperson sales of 40 also (Jack).

Comment: still puts Soap before Paper

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks.